# Ruby inner flatten (array of arrays)

Tags: arrays, ruby, flatten

I have an array like the following

```
[
  [[0, :a], [2, :b]],
  [3, :c],
  [4, :d],
  [[5, :e], [6, :f], [7, :g]]
]
```

That is, an Array of elements that are either (1) 2-element Arrays, or (2) an Array of 2-element Arrays.

I am trying to find an elegant way to "flatten" this array such that elements that are (2) get expanded out into root-level elements. In this example:

```
[[0, :a], [2, :b], [3, :c], [4, :d], [5, :e], [6, :f], [7, :g]]
```

This is almost like using `Array#flatten(depth)`, except `depth` needs to work from the inside out, rather than the outside in.

The actual arrays can get very large, so I do not want to push (`<<`) elements onto a new Array in a loop for performance reasons. For some reason I cannot think of how to use any combination of `map`, `flatten`, `flat_map`, or other more efficient `Enumerable` methods to accomplish this without writing a C++-style preallocate-and-populate loop. Can anyone think of a more Rubyist way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do is:

```
array.flatten.each_slice(2).to_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting another solution here for posterity:

```
array.flat_map{|el| el.first.is_a?(Array) ? el : [el]}
```

This solution also handles if the innermost Arrays are of variable length -- that is, the total Array is an Array of (1) n-element Arrays or (2) Arrays of n-element Arrays, where n is not necessarily the same for any given element. For example

```
[
  [1,2,3],
  [[4,5], [6,7,8,9]]
]
```